# Use calendar form field in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using a calendar field in Joomla component template.

But i have no idea how to use it. the example XML field definition is

```
<field name="mycalendar" type="calendar" default="5-10-2008" label="Select a date" description="" format="%d-%m-%Y" />
```

But how to define it in a php template?

Thank you!

After using the code, how can i make the calendar icon align with the input box?
now it is like this

[image]

thank you.

hi, as for the code, i am insert the date into database of field name 'from' and 'to', so where do i need to change the code to match that?

```
<?php
    echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'from', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
?>

<?php
    echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'to', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

This will add a calendar to the form.

```
<?php
    echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'mycalendar', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
  ?>
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: it works, but there is some minor problem, please see my edited question.

Comment: do you want to use date picker from XML form fields  ?

Comment: I think the icon issue is due to width of the DIV try to increase the width of calender placed tag(Span,div)

Comment: how to use the date picker?

Comment: hi, i also want to implement a custom field to pick the time, can you give me some guide line?

Comment: did you mean setting the date from database to fields  ? or to the DB for submitting form you will get post data in from and to fields. For setting the date from DB to the calender set first argument.

Comment: as for a input box, it has a name, for example 'from', this box must have the same name of the related field name in database, how can i set the input box name, of the calendar form field?

Comment: set second argument,It will create a hidden field with that name

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line at the top of your output file:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.calendar');
```

And if your XML is correct everything should work.